# How to parse text for feed with php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Using Wikipedia API link to get some basic informations about some world known characters.

Example : (About [Richard Maibaum](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&list=search&srsearch=Richard%20Maibaum&srlimit=1))

This would show as following
[image: Richard Maibaum Wikipedia]

**Now my question** I'd like to parse the xml to get such basic informations between `<search></search>` to show it.

here is the code i'm willing to use if it right ~ thanks to [ccKep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1179287/cckep) ~

```
<?PHP
ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");

$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&list=search&srsearch=Richard Maibaum&srlimit=1";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$extracts = $xml->xpath("/api/query/search");

echo $extracts["0"];
?>
```

But it failed and gives blank output

So any help ~ thanks

Comment: so what's your question? Does your code fail? how does it fail?

Comment: @MrSoundless _Updated the question_ yes it failed and gives blank output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is your problem, but you can get your search results like this.

```
 strip_tags($extracts[0]->p['snippet']));
```

Comment: you solved both :) in fact the output was blank but your code shows me that i wrong something wrong in array so now it works perfect. ~ thanks

Comment: echo strip_tags($extracts[0]->p['snippet']); //Richard Maibaum (May 26, 1909 - January 4, 1991) was an American film producer , playwright and screenwriter best known for his .. (exactly like i want) ~ thanks